# Hibernate: What's wrong with this mapping to a subclass joined on foreign key?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, mapping, one-to-many

I am experimenting with Hibernate to gain experience. I created a class `Person` with two subclasses: `Student` and `Worker`:

```
public abstract class Person {
    private Long id;
    ...
}

public class Student extends Person { ... }
```

Another class, `Employer`, has a bidirectional one-to-many relationship with `Worker`.

```
public class Worker extends Person {
    private Employer employer;
    ...
}

public class Employer {
    private String taxId;
    private Set<Worker> employees = new HashSet<Worker>();
    ...
}
```

for which the mapping is

```
<class name="Employer" table="EMPLOYER">
    <id name="taxId" column="TAX_ID" length="11">
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    ...
    <set name="employees" inverse="true">
        <key column="EMPLOYER_TAX_ID"/>
        <one-to-many class="Worker"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

The inheritance hierarchy is modelled with a mixed strategy, where `Student` is mapped to the `PERSON` table, but `Worker` is stored in its own table, joined with a foreign key:

```
<class name="Person" table="PERSON">
    <id name="id" column="PERSON_ID" type="long" unsaved-value="0">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="PERSON_TYPE" type="string"/>
    ...
    <subclass name="Student" discriminator-value="STU"> ... </subclass>

    <subclass name="Worker" discriminator-value="WRK">
        <join table="WORKER">
            <key column="WORKER_ID"/>
            <many-to-one name="employer" column="EMPLOYER_TAX_ID" cascade="save-update"/>
            ...
        </join>
    </subclass>
</class>
```

I use Apache Derby 10.5.3.0 and autogenerate the schema by setting `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `create-drop`.

To test all this, I created a DBUnit test with the following dataset:

```
<EMPLOYER   TAX_ID          = "1234567890"
            ...
/>
<PERSON   PERSON_ID         = "12345"
          PERSON_TYPE       = "WRK"
          ...
/>
<WORKER   WORKER_ID         = "12345"
          EMPLOYER_TAX_ID   = "1234567890"
          ...
/>
```

I have a test which loads the worker entity and verifies that it has the correct employee. This passes. Then a test for the opposite direction:

```
    String taxId = "1234567890";

    Employer employer = (Employer) session.get(Employer.class, taxId);

    assertNotNull(employer);
    assertThat(employer.getEmployees().size(), is(1));
```

**Upon execution, the last assert fails because the set of employees is empty.**

Digging deeper, I found that for some reason **Hibernate looks for (and creates) the EMPLOYER_TAX_ID column in table PERSON instead of WORKER**! It is also present in WORKER, but that one is not used in the query. The select statements for populating the set of employees is:

```
select
    employees0_.EMPLOYER_TAX_ID as EMPLOYER10_1_,
    employees0_.PERSON_ID as PERSON1_1_,
    employees0_.PERSON_ID as PERSON1_1_0_,
    employees0_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST3_1_0_,
    employees0_.FAMILY_NAME as FAMILY4_1_0_,
    employees0_.DATE_OF_BIRTH as DATE5_1_0_,
    employees0_.HOME_ADDRESS as HOME6_1_0_,
    employees0_.CITY as CITY1_0_,
    employees0_.ZIP as ZIP1_0_,
    employees0_1_.EMPLOYER_TAX_ID as EMPLOYER2_2_0_,
    employees0_1_.JOB_TITLE as JOB3_2_0_,
    employees0_1_.JOB_GRADE as JOB4_2_0_,
    employees0_1_.START_DATE as START5_2_0_ 
from
    PERSON employees0_ 
inner join
    WORKER employees0_1_ 
        on employees0_.PERSON_ID=employees0_1_.WORKER_ID 
where
    employees0_.EMPLOYER_TAX_ID=?
```

Why is this? And **how can I make Hibernate find EMPLOYER_TAX_ID in the WORKER table?**

Note that since this is an experimental project, I can change just about anything. I appreciate any workarounds, but I would prefer understanding what's going on and fixing this mapping as it is (as much as possible).

**Update:** if I switch to a clean `<joined-subclass>` inheritance mapping strategy, the generated schema looks as it should and the test passes. This is a good enough workaround, but I am still curious whether there is a way to make the mixed strategy work properly.

Comment: Why still use those nasty XML file's if you can use JPA annotations?

Comment: @Kdeveloper Our real project uses XML, so this is my prime target to experiment with. But I will extend my pet project to annotations in the future, as time allows...

Comment: Just for later reference, a one-to-many bidirectional relationship would be defined using annotations as follows:
`@OneToMany(mappedBy="nameOfSingleInstanceInOtherEntity")`,  `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="nameWhichYouWishToGiveToIdField")`

Comment: @James P. Very kind of you, thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like known bug: http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1015

It is known since ages and has been reported tons of times.  Still, they are not fixing it...

Comment: By the way, the problem with <joined-subclass> is that it results in huge queries.  Not so huge with two subclasses, but each next subclass adds to SQL size considerably.

Comment: Thanks, this really seems to be the same case!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I fixed it in this way:
Changing subclass by joined-sublclass.
In your case it would be:

```xml
<joined-subclass name="Worker" table="WORKER">
    <key column="WORKER_ID"/>
    <many-to-one name="employer" column="EMPLOYER_TAX_ID" cascade="save-update"/>  
    ...  
</joined-subclass>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using a joined subclass implies there's no way to use another innheritance strategy. Maybe there's [no chance to do that](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-mixing-tableperclass-tablepersubclass).