# Map hibernate many-to-one with the foreign key in subclass joined table

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm mapping some entities using **Hibernate 3** for my project and simply explained I've got kind of this:

- `Student` entity (*tstudent* table)
- `UniversityStudent` entity (*tuniversitystudent* table)
- `University` entity (*tuniversity* table)

`UniversityStudent` extends from `Student` and has its own attributes, like the university itself, which is a foreign key into the *tuniversitystudent* table. It is also mapped like a subclass into the `Student` class, using a **discriminator** field:

```xml
<class name="mycompany.Student" table="tstudent" discriminator-value="BASIC">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <discriminator column="type" />
    <property name="name" column="name" />
    <property name="surname" column="surname" />
    <property name="phoneNumber" column="phone_number" />
    <subclass discriminator-value="UNIVERSITY"
            name="mycompany.UniversityStudent">
        <join table="tuniversitystudent">
            <key column="id_student" />
            <many-to-one name="university" class="mycompany.University">
                <column name="id_university" />
            </many-to-one>
        </join>
    </subclass>
</class>
```

Well, now I want to have a `Set` collection with the `UniversityStudent` entities for each `University`. So I map it like that:

```xml
<class name="mycompany.University" table="tuniversity">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" />
    <set name="universityStudents" table="tuniversitystudent">
        <key>
            <column name="id_university" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="mycompany.UniversityStudent" />
    </set>
</class>
```

My problem comes when I want to load a `University` object, Hibernate complains that `id_university` doesn't exist in *tstudent* table. I checked the generated SQL query and it really tries to load it from *tstudent*.

> Unknown column 'student0_.id_university' in 'field list'

It seems that it's recognizing that it is a subclass of the basic `Student` and tries to join the collection using a field in the parent table, but however the field is actually in the child table, because only university students can have a University assigned.

I tried another workaround which seems to work but it's not valid for me, that's mapping the `UniversityStudent` as a `joined-subclass` instead of a `subclass` with a **join** inside:

```xml
<joined-subclass name="mycompany.UniversityStudent" table="tuniversitystudent">
    <key column="id_student" />
    <many-to-one name="university" class="mycompany.University">
        <column name="id_university" />
    </many-to-one>
</joined-subclass>
```

However, I'm interested in keeping it as a subclass with a discriminator value. Any idea?

Comment: why do you keep using hbm.xml files?? They're so messy

Comment: Not every legacy project is portable to JPA annotations due to time reasons. And I don't see any mess here.

Comment: Might be silly question - is type column having 'UNIVERSITY' for university student records in DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked out some resources and finally got into this bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1015, which looks absolutely compatible with your case. Checkout [this old question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621733/hibernate-whats-wrong-with-this-mapping-to-a-subclass-joined-on-foreign-key), again very similar to your case.
I firstly read the definition of [table per sublass](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass) given by Hibernate (I know, it is for version 3.3 but I couldn't find the same source for Hibernate 4): `joined-subclass` seems (to me) to be a custom implementation of `subclass using a discriminator` provided by Hibernate and that is a good reason to stay away from its usage. However, from what I know, the mappings [table per sublass](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass) and [table per subclass using a discriminator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass-discriminator) should be equivalent, that's why I believe the bug I pointed you out is really still open.
If you have time and will, you can try to use another JPA provider and check if you still run in the same issue. [JPA 2.0 specifications](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-javadocs.zip) is a thing, provider implementation is another! I recently run into another bug (related to `@IdClass`) which forced me to try [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) and the configuration which was not working with Hibernate was right with Eclipse Link

Comment: The links you provided are actually very related to my problem. @yair provided me a workaround, but it seems your reply really explains the root of the problem. However some posters talk about a `limitation` and not a `bug`. I don't really think that should be considered a `limitation` having read the Hibernate guide.

Comment: I read @yair's answer before posting my research, mostly because I got interesting in the `Custom SQL for loading`. I don't know if it is a bug or a limitation, but unfortunately as you also read it hass been signaled years ago and apparently not yet fixed in version 4. Go with yair's solution, it's clean!

Answer (score 1):

Seems you can use [Custom SQL (or HQL) for loading](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#querysql-load). Haven't tried it myself, but looks like, hmm, at least as a last resort, it provides a decent solution.

Define the query in your HBM:

```xml
<sql-query name="universityStudents">
    <load-collection alias="unistu" role="University.universityStudents"/>
    SELECT unistu.*, student.*
    FROM tuniversitystudent unistu 
    JOIN tstudent student 
    ON unistu.id_student = student.id
    WHERE unistu.id_university = :id
</sql-query>
```

And then use it inside `University`:

```xml
<set name="universityStudents" inverse="true">
    <key/>
    <one-to-many class="mycompany.UniversityStudent"/>
    <loader query-ref="universityStudents"/>
</set>
```

Comment: @XtremeBiker don't know. But if [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18044526/978502) solves the problem then it's figured out :).

Comment: @XtremeBiker great! Thanks for the edit. I'll try to give the problem another look.

Comment: @XtremeBiker seems your edit was rejected by some reviewers. I'll add your variation. As far as I understand, you had some consequent problem with column in the parent and child that their names collide.